# Why does Outlook 2010 show my title on two lines?

Tags: html, outlook, newsletter

I used a template to create an HTML newsletter for my company. I have very little knowledge of any programming language which is why I began with a template. I've sent a few tests to my work email address (outlook 2010) and to my personal email (gmail). It looks great in my gmail but in outlook it decides to put the title of the newsletter slightly staggered with the word 'news' below the word "focus",under and slightly off to the left really. Please see this image to see what I mean:[image]
  I want to know how to alter the code so that it shows up in outlook the way it shows up in gmail, all on one line?

Also I really don't know if I've shown too much code below; or not enough, all I know is that the title part is in there, any help for a total beginner would be much appreaciated

```
<div id="SpeBkDiv" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<!--100% body table-->
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
             <!--email container-->
             <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                 <tbody>
                     <tr>
                         <td>
                         <!--header-->
                         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                             <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td valign="top">
                                     <img src="image url here" alt="" height="12" width="600" />
                                     <!--top links-->
                                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="52" width="600">
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td valign="middle" width="221">
                                                 <p style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Times New Roman; color: #333; margin: 0px;" align="center"><br />
                                                 </p>
                                                 </td>
                                             </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                     <!--/top links-->
                                     <!--line break-->
                                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="14" width="600">
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td valign="top" width="600">
                                                 <p>
                                                 <img src="image url here" alt="" height="10" width="600" />
                                                 </p>
                                                 </td>
                                             </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                     <!--/line break-->
                                     <!--header content-->
                                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="168" width="600">
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td>
                                                 <h1 style="color: #333 !important; margin: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana" align="center">
                                                 <span style="font-size: 50pt; color: #808080;">
                                                 <a title="image name" href="image url here">
                                                 <img style="text-align: left; float: left;" alt="" src="image url here" align="left" height="79" width="103" />
                                                 </a>
                                                 </span>
                                                 </h1>
                                                 <h1 style="color: #333 !important; margin: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana;" align="center">
                                                 <span style="font-size: 45pt; color: #808080;">
                                                 <c>
                                                 <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40pt;">Focus News</span>
                                                 </c>
                                                 </span>
                                                 <span style="font-size: 50pt; color: #808080;">
                                                 </span>
                                                 <currentmonthname style="font-size: 36pt; color: #333333;">
                                                 <currentyear>
                                                 </currentyear>
                                                 </currentmonthname>
                                                 </h1>
                                                 </td>
                                                 <td id="issue" style="background-image: url('images/issue-no.jpg'); background-color: #98AFC7; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top; width: 109px; height: 109px;" bgcolor="#98AFC7" valign="top">
                                                 <!--number-->
                                                 <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" height="81" width="126">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td>
                                                             <div align="center">
                                                             <h4>
                                                             <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana;">Issue no.7</span>
                                                             </h4>
                                                             </div>
                                                             <div align="center">
                                                             <h4>
                                                             <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana;">July</span>
                                                             <span style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana;">2012</span>
                                                             </h4>
                                                             </div>
                                                             </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                 </table>
                                                 <!--/number-->
                                                 <br />
                                                 </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to validate your html. Try visiting http://validator.w3.org/check and either paste in your code or browse to your html file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and on Outlook2007 (I don't have the newest version) works great.
What I can see is that you have  tags around Focus News. Get rid of those, they probably are wrongly interpreted by Outlook and add some extra space at the beginning of the line. Also the two nested spans look weird. So my suggestion is transform these lines:

```
 <span style="font-size: 45pt; color: #808080;">
    <c>
        <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40pt;">Focus News</span>
    </c>
 </span>
```

to this

```
<span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40pt;">Focus News</span>
```

P.S. It is probably pointless to validate your code, as suggested in the previous answer, as newsletters use standards that date back to 1999. But keep the markup as clean as possible (here you can find some interesting guidelines http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)